# Oracle GoldenGate adapter for Kafka - JSON message contents

Tags: apache-kafka, oracle-golden-gate

In My golden gate big data for kafka. when i try to update the record  am getting only updated column and primary key column in after part in json file

```
{"table":"MYSCHEMATOPIC.PASSPORTS","op_type":"U","op_ts":"2018-03-17 13:57:50.000000","current_ts":"2018-03-17T13:57:53.901000","pos":"00000000030000010627","before":{"PASSPORT_ID":71541893,"PPS_ID":71541892,"PASSPORT_NO":"1234567","PASSPORT_NO_NUMERIC":241742,"PASSPORT_TYPE_ID":7,"ISSUE_DATE":null,"EXPIRY_DATE":"0060-12-21 00:00:00","ISSUE_PLACE_EN":"UN-DEFINED","ISSUE_PLACE_AR":"?????? ????????","ISSUE_COUNTRY_ID":203,"ISSUE_GOV_COUNTRY_ID":203,"IS_ACTIVE":1,"PREV_PASSPORT_ID":null,"CREATED_DATE":"2003-06-08 00:00:00","CREATED_BY":-9,"MODIFIED_DATE":null,"MODIFIED_BY":null,"IS_SETTLED":0,"MAIN_PASSPORT_PERSON_INFO_ID":34834317,"NATIONALITY_ID":590},
"after":{"PASSPORT_ID":71541893,"NATIONALITY_ID":589}}
```

In After part  in my json out i want to show all columns

How to get all columns in after part?

```
gg.handlerlist = kafkahandler
gg.handler.kafkahandler.type=kafka gg.handler.kafkahandler.KafkaProducerConfigFile=custom_kafka_producer.properties
    #The following resolves the topic name using the short table name
    gg.handler.kafkahandler.topicMappingTemplate=passports

    gg.handler.kafkahandler.format=json
    gg.handler.kafkahandler.BlockingSend =false
    gg.handler.kafkahandler.includeTokens=false
    gg.handler.kafkahandler.mode=op
    #gg.handler.kafkahandler.format.insertOpKey=I
    #gg.handler.kafkahandler.format.updateOpKey=U
    #gg.handler.kafkahandler.format.deleteOpKey=D
    #gg.handler.kafkahandler.format.truncateOpKey=T
    #gg.handler.kafkahandler.format.includeColumnNames=TRUE
    goldengate.userexit.timestamp=utc
    goldengate.userexit.writers=javawriter
    javawriter.stats.display=TRUE
    javawriter.stats.full=TRUE
    gg.log=log4j
    gg.log.level=info
  gg.report.time=30sec
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [Kafka Connect handler](https://docs.oracle.com/goldengate/bd123110/gg-bd/GADBD/using-kafka-connect-handler.htm#GADBD-GUID-22C9C4B2-48B0-4116-BD21-45D94F9296EC) instead - this includes the full payload. [This article](https://rmoff.net/2017/11/21/installing-oracle-goldengate-for-big-data-12.3.1-with-kafka-connect-and-confluent-platform/) goes through the setup process.

Comment: This article is no longer available. What setting to get all columns in payload before and after image?

Comment: I've fixed the link

Comment: Looks good, and even though I am a Confluent fan, I take it that if you leave out the schema drift aspect this can all run without Confluent?

Comment: If you don't want to use Avro, yes it's just vanilla Apache Kafka. But you [generally should use Avro](https://www.confluent.io/blog/schemas-contracts-compatibility/) :)

Comment: No I agree with you, but we have a use case here in which Schema drift is not so dynamic and very controlled. But I have used it elsewhere and have read your articles! Good weekend.

Comment: The link you have kindly provided is no longer a real answer given the new versions one needs to download. Installing OGG fraught with all sorts of issues.

Comment: To be quite honest, you may need to re-write this as we want to download 19c and then there are libraries not found, ensure adapters not clear. I could not get it to work, back ot the days of fusion, streams issues. terribly disappointing

Comment: Feel free to collate any updates or write a new version - happy to either host it on my article or you can on your own blog and I'll update my answer to link to yours :)

Comment: Robin, I can see you are also highly competent and part of RM now, I did some work from R at one stage. But following it all when not all stuff available from OTN makes it hard to follow. For example you could state you need classic and BD version. On the 19c I could not find adapters, or if still needed. Problem is stuff becomes outdated. In any event I got it to work with 19c up until BD part. But need symbolic links, that would be nice to know... Good effort still

Comment: I've not been at RM for a while :) Feel free to drop me an email robin@rmoff.net if you've got any edits etc you'd like me to make to the blog.

Comment: Gotcha, ok, will do.

Answer (score 0):

Hi This issue is fixed by added below change in golden gate side

ADD TRANDATA table_name ALLCOLS